# autoLink:"all" - different in some languages

Tags: android, textview

I use in a TextView the **android:autoLink** feature with parameter "**all**"!

If I use the **german language** the number **037399** is a link.
I can tap on it to open the dialer.

If I change the language to **english** this number isn't a link anymore.

Why? I want that all numbers are clickable no matter which language.

**For example:**

Text "Call Joe 037399" is in german language clickable.
The same text with english language isn't!

**My TextView:**

```
 <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvMessage"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:minHeight="@dimen/dialog_line_item_height"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:autoLink="all"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                    android:singleLine="false"
                    tools:text="TextLine 1"
                    android:textColor="?android:textColorPrimary"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because it checks the contact number format is valid for the country or not. So, it depends on your Local selected.

In German the phone number are in that format but in english is not a valid number for calling as english is basically refers to US.

Comment: Why is it not a valid phone number in US/english?

Comment: each country has their own specific format for phone number. If you can ask this you can also say why we have different country code or zip code

Comment: Yes of course, but I meant the number "037399" is a number. In EVERY country. In German/Austria the format is "+43 37399" for example. Or "0043 37399", but of course you can also call "037399" and I think in US/english it is the same. If you type "037399" in your phone you call a number isn't it? ;-) And the user who reported this is from the US so it seems it is a legit phone number.

Comment: which locale you have selected

Comment: I or the user have selected Locale US